Capture extent of each .las file in a directory as text or polygon without loading into QGIS
I have been sent some large point-cloud datasets without any clear indication as to the area that each directory covers. If I load them into QGIS they take forever, even when showing just extents. I'm looking for a solution that just reads each file, extracts the extents and saves this without bringing them into the map canvas. Then I can select just the one(es) I want.

LASInfo in LASTools will give you that quickly. Search "lasinfo" in the Processing Toolbox.

The pdal tindex command is used to create a tile index vector geometry file for PDAL-readable point cloud types - Doc, Tutorial

You could use QGIS processing polygonfromlayerextent from layer - tools and use it in batch processing mode

then open .las files from directory (that's doesn't load them to map)

select directory to save with new file prefix

next select to name layers by original file names

start and you have extents in seperete files

if you want to merge them use mergevectorlayes

Thank you- this gives me exactly what I want. Sorry I took some time to work through your instructions. For the benefit of others, I found that the first step in QGIS 3.40 was called "Extract layer extent". The input "Select to name layers" required a name for the Geopackage files, though this was used as a prefix. Last, "Merge Vector layers" requires a separate process and can be found under the heading "Vector general". The processing is fast and shows as completed in tens of seconds but I found no way to prevent indexing of the las files after- even with option to "Load layers turned off.
